# Entity framework one to many - empty virtual collection

Tags: entity-framework-6, one-to-many

I have this code first database

```
public partial class SystemWarning
{

    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// id of the admin that created the entry
    /// </summary>
    public string CreatedById { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string AcknowledgedById { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AcknowledgedBy { get; set; }

}
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public AspNetUser()
    {
        SystemWarnings = new HashSet<SystemWarning>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SystemWarning> SystemWarnings { get; set; }

}
```

And linked together as follows

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.SystemWarnings)
            .WithOptional(e => e.CreatedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

For reasons that escape me at the moment, when I extract my AspNetUser, the SystemWarnings collection is always empty, even if there are systemwarnings that are linked to the AspNetUser in the database.

I have a bunch of these 1-n links, even on the same object, and the other links remain non empty, and for now I'm not seeing the difference.

@edit: here's that other object for comparison:

```
    public partial class UserProfile: BaseObject
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser Owner { get; set; }

}

and the mapping

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OwnedUserProfiles)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Owner)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);
```

Seems the same to me, except that the SystemWarning has a long as Id with identity specs (forgot to post that before - it's defined as follows)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemWarning>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

And that SystemWarning actually has another reference to the AspNetUser that I now added (AcknowledgedBy(Id)) which is linked as follows

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUser>()
            .HasMany(e => e.SystemWarnings)
            .WithOptional(e => e.AcknowledgedBy)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.AcknowledgedById).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I'll post the SQL trace soon...

Comment: Where is your query?

Comment: Assuming your query has the proper `Include(user => user.SystemWarnings)` then I would first examine the [logged SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception).

Comment: the query to extract the data is very simple

    Model.AspNetUser existingObject = context.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == id);

then access existingObject.SystemWarnings (which is empty) and OwnedUserProfiles (which contains data)

Answer (score 0):

Well, that edit did the trick.. both links from SystemWarning to AspNetUser are mapped on the SystemWarnings collection.. no wonder that's not working the way it's supposed to.

Note to myself.. map every 1:n to a different collection or there'll be trouble.